# Find the curl of the following

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\underline{c} \space$ be a constant vector.

$$\underline{F}=r^2\underline{c}+2(\underline{c}\cdot\underline{r})\underline{r}$$

How would I solve $r^2$, would it be cross multiplication?

Comment: I have difficulty to understand this post. Is your question just what the $r^2$ means? Why isn't it $\underline{r}^2$ or what is the relation between $r$ and $\underline{r}$? It might also be that the connection to curl is not apparent to everyone. Maybe you could add that via an [edit].

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve $r^2$, I know $r=(x,y,z)$ but was not sure how to multiply $r$ and $r$ together without cross or dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r^2$$ ist just r*r so the same as $$|r|^2$$
trula